# Using remote database

Tags: android, database

I am building a free app that stores addresses of nearby hospitals in database. User can add a hospital too. Since this is a free app, I can't invest in server space.

I already know how to package your pre-populated database with your app. However, I'm thinking of creating a database file and uploading it to Dropbox. Then I open connection to it and retrieve or add records.

If possible, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea would be creating a web-service which you can then query in your application. This service would be hosted in "the cloud" (there are multiple free hosters like Google App Engine).

This way, you can manage your data in a real database, query it from your application, create a synchronization functionality (which downloads parts of your data and makes it available offline) and much more.

Comment: Google App Engine has made Cloud SQL as paid service. Do you have any other leads? My data will be hardly 3 MB max.

Comment: @deeJ Heroku is also free (except the databases). But I'm sure there was an add-on for MySQL database (hosted somewhere else) in there. Have a look.

Comment: Actually my need is just for a flat table. So, I find that Google Fusion Tables fit the bill perfectly. Thanks a ton for pointing me in right direction. It would have been impossible for me to find out. Thanks again.